# Gradle build error configuring project - Android Studio 2.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit, build.gradle

After updating SDK build tools, error:

```
Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I am getting the following error message when I try to run my code in Android Studio 2.3

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> Could not download junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12)
>     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
>         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
>             akamai.bintray.com**

build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module:App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "palstech.com.fitnessdroid2"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows
Here is the build.gradle file:

`buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
`

Comment: please post it in your question, formatted.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I have edited the question, please check.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post both of your `build.gradle` files to be sure. Its good that you have `jcenter()` in the `allprojects` block.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Done!

Comment: @ApoorvaMathur Make sure your System is connected to internet when you're building your project

Comment: It all looks fine do me. Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Yes I am connected to the internet. After updating a few SDK build tools the error is replaced by another one as I have updated in my question.

Comment: Now it looks like you have a `javac` problem. What version of java do you have?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I have updated to version 8. After making the changes suggested by you, updating some other components and removing `junit:junit:4.12` the studio works fine. I am able to run apps on my phone. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line , inside repositories.

`maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }`

Comment: Thank you for your input.
I did as said which led to another error:
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript'.
> com/android/jill/api/ConfigNotSupportedException`

Answer (score 0):

Specify url of repository in your root `build.gradle` file,

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
    }
}
```

Refresh dependency if still not able to build try this:

**application/project** -> **module settings**-> **Dependencies tab** -> find **junit:junit:4.12** -> select it and right click and choose **remove** option -> ok

**EDIT**

Make sure gradle plugins are latest for your new error :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense and is redundant.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I suggested to add `maven` repo, may be not able to find it in `jcenter`, I know that is available in jcenter. And in other suggestion, some time artifact linked with project but not selected in dependency so I informed to cross check that

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Removing the `junit:junit:4.12` component helped. I am able to sync and run my projects now. Thank you so much for your help!